# How to create a Office 365 Outlook alias from .NET via API

Tags: .net, api, email, alias, office365

Is there a way to create a new alias to a email address in office 365 from a .net application / webpage? I've looked for a API, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that you can use PowerShell to add aliases to a email address. And PowerShell can be used with c# to connect to Office 365.

**Connect to Office 365 with .NET with PowerShell**

http://gsexdev.blogspot.se/2011/07/running-exchange-online-and-office-365.html

**Add alias to a email adress with PowerShell**

http://wdmsb.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/powershell-for-office-365/