# Creating email alias using office 365 api

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have a office 365 email account.I want to set this as a primary account and i wrote a service to download attachments in particular time interval.In my project there is a situation where the system generated email alias names only for this primary email account. I want to **create** these **email alias** in office 365 api using c#.net project. I Don't want to enter any credentials at run time.

Comment: Do you want to create O365 account with rest api ?

Comment: I have an account. I want to create alias for that account using O365 api via c#.net code.

Comment: I found a similar post here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501113/how-to-create-a-office-365-outlook-alias-from-net-via-api.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an O365 account and want to add alias to the primary email address . As a workaround , you could use powershell to set primary email address and add Alias address :

```
Set-Mailbox <Identity> -EmailAddress <Primary Email Address>,<Alias Email Address>
```

If you want to add alias email address as bulk mode , you could create a csv file to contain alias email address information (columns may contain userID , alias email address) , then you could use powershell to read this csv file and update related users in Exchange Online . Please click [here](http://o365info.com/manage-email-address-using-powershell/) for more details and demo .

Comment: My requirement is to create email alias using office 365 api in c#.net project.

Comment: @bijupranavam,AFAIK, O365 api currently doesn't support that .You could call the powershell to achieve that in your c# code.

Comment: Hi team, any luck on creating alias programmatically using C#